# Why my bot's prefix isnt worked? const prefix = "N!";

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Full Code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["DIRECT_MESSAGES", "GUILDS"]});

const prefix = "N!";

client.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const args = commandBody.split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


    if (command === "ping") {
        const timeTaken = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
        message.reply(`Pong! This message had a latency of ${timeTaken}ms.`);
    }
});
client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

I start the bot, write a command... And nothing. Code is taken from the lesson. I hope for a quick answer because it will be useful to me.

Comment: Have you checked if the function you provide to `client.on("message", ...)` is actually executing when you write a message?

Comment: Also, "... from the lesson" is very inexplicit. Please provide any additional information you can, like specifying which lesson in what course, if you expect us to know what lesson you're talking about and help you in regards to that.

Comment: @Phoenix1355, to be honest, this is essentially my first job in programming. I wanted to create a bot, and see what it consists of, and here is the "lesson" https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-discord-bot-with-node-js-ru

Comment: But did the function callback get executed when you typed something in a channel where the bot is active?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but the bot simply does not respond to my commands. I wrote the code in visual studio code. I just enabled the bot with the node index.js command and went to check it in discord. The debug console, temrinal, etc. is empty

Comment: Okay, this seems like it might not be a problem with your code. Make sure that when run the index.js file, that the bot status changes to green. If it doesn't turn green, there might be an issue with the way you created your project. Verify that the authentication token from the bot is identical in the config.json file.

Comment: That's just the point, when I turn it on it turns green, that is, on the network

Comment: put a console.log("got here!") message right before the message.author.bot check.  See if you're getting in the handler at all.  Then move the console.log messages down and debug is old-school. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, I think there must be an error in the management of the arguments of the command that is entered by the user.

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    const args = [];
    message.content.match(new RegExp('"[^"]+"|[\\S]+', 'g')).forEach(element => {
        if (!element) return;
        return args.push(element.replace(/"/g, ''));
    });
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase().substring(prefix.length);
    
    if (command === 'ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong !');
    }
}
```